# Circular radius intersection (like a circular cursor brush) - Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to be able to catch the faces of an object in the radius of a circular cursor (like in painting/photoshop).

I'll show you what is it for https://jsfiddle.net/Shaggisu/w7ufmutr/9/

I'd want be able to selct not only the single face that in the moment intersects with the mouse point but all faces that might be in the circular radius, I tried to uplod some image for that cursor but cant really make it work with external files in jsfiddle.

My question is, if is there some standard method of achieving multiple selection/intersection in a specified radius or should I devised some code that would for example reiterate on suroundin faces around the mouse point in specific moment.

I'm still quite new to three.js so I would ask for some directions to go with it, and especialy if there are some solid ways to achieve, any tip would be helpful too.

```
    var brushTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '/cur_circle.png' );
var brushMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: brushTexture, useScreenCoordinates: true, alignment: THREE.SpriteAlignment.center } );


  brushSprite = new THREE.Sprite( brushMaterial );
  brushSprite.scale.set( 32, 32, 1.0 );
  brushSprite.position.set( 50, 50, 0 );
  scene.add( brushSprite );
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // initialize object to perform world/screen calculations
    projector = new THREE.Projector();

    // when the mouse moves, call the given function
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

}

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) 
{
    // the following line would stop any other event handler from firing
    // (such as the mouse's TrackballControls)

    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("Click.");


    // update the mouse variable
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    // find intersections

    // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
    //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList );

    // if there is one (or more) intersections
    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {
  controls.enabled = false;  // stops camera rotation

        console.log("Hit @ " + toString( intersects[0].point ) );
        // change the color of the closest face.
        intersects[ 0 ].face.color.setRGB( 0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2, 0, 0 ); 
        intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    }
}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event){

event.preventDefault();

mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

brushSprite.position.set( event.clientX, event.clientY, 0);

// find intersections

    // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
    //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList );

    // if there is one (or more) intersections
    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {
        console.log("Hit @ " + toString( intersects[0].point ) );
        // change the color of the closest face.
        intersects[ 0 ].face.color.setRGB( 0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2, 0, 0 ); 
        intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    }

document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
}

function onDocumentMouseUp( event){

event.preventDefault();

document.removeEventListener( "mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove);

controls.enabled = true;
}
```

The code is modified version of the stemkoskis github that I used for practice.
I have already extended it somewhat for camera management in intersection events and continous selection, but the selection of multiple faces in a radius is what interests me now the most.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in javascript, modifying vertex color, like you do it in your sample but you will be quickly limited by the number of polygon.

That said, consider your brush like a cone, which start from the Ray.origin and extend in Ray.direction. The radius of the cone is driven by the radius of your brush.

- Iterate over each vertices.
- For each, get the minimum distance between the vertex to the Ray line.
- Get the radius of the brush/cone based on the distance between this vertex and the Ray.origin
- If the minimum distance is inferior to the cone radius, your vertex is "in". You can also handle the distance to create a smooth brush.

It should looks like this, it kind of pseudo code, you may need to adapt to ThreeJs Math lib:

```
// Important, Ray origin and direction must be defined in the same space a vertices positions
// You may need to transform ray origin and direction in object local space.


// get the length of Ray.direction
// may be useless if 'direction' is normalized
var rayDirLenSq = ray.direction.length();
rayDirLenSq *= rayDirLenSq;

var brushRadius = 10.0;


for( var i=0;i< vertices.length;i++){

  // get the vertex
  var v = vertices[i];

  var vdir = v.sub( ray.origin );

  var dot = vdir.dot( ray.direction ) / rayDirLenSq;

  if( dot < 0 ){
    // handle vertices behind the camera if needed
  }

  // v2 : projection of the vertex onto ray line
  var v2 = ray.direction.clone().multiplyScalar( dot );

  // v3 : projection -> vertex
  var v3 = vdir.subtract( v2 )

  // dist is the distance between the vertex and the ray line
  var dist = v3.length()

  // 0 when vertex is at the brush border
  // 1 when vertex is in the brush center
  var paintingFactor = Math.max(0.0, 1.0 - dist/brushRadius )


}
```

Depending of what you want, you can store the painting factor of each vertices to get a mean factor per faces. Or you can modify vertex color of each vertices independantly to get gradients on your faces...

I didn't test the code, it may contain some mistakes :)

### A more advanced method

You could also use a texture to paint on. You will get rid of vertex (and javascript) limitations. You will be able to paint with textured brushes, and have detail inside a triangle (no more vertex color).

The principle : 
You need UVs datas and a texture + FBO for each of your meshes.

In a prepass, for each mesh, render it to it's Fbo in it's uvs coords

```
gl_Position = vec4( UVs*2.0-1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```

Provide the worldSpace vertex position to fragment shader, so you can access the world space position of each pixel of the object texture.

```
vVertexPosition = modelMatrix * aPosition;
```

With *vVertexPosition* in your fragment shader, you can then use the same method as the javascript one to get the brushFactor of each *pixels* of your mesh.
You can even project this world space pixel position in a custom projection matrix  based on the Ray to get the uvs coordinate of the pixel in a brush texture, and paint with textured brush.

Comment: Thank you for such a wide and thought through comment, to adress texture painting It was the first form in which I started my project but didnt work out for other elements that took part in its progress, namely too complex 3d meshes for automaticaly generated UV maps, at least for now but I still have different approach to develop,
although I would like to create a brush for this very basic version vertex painting, so I can grasp better understanding of the rays, intersections possibilities and managing those for my needs, from what I see 3js actually have origin, direction struct,

TY.